# Heartbeat / New Post Notification

Tags: php, wordpress, heartbeat

I run a WordPress site with a lot of traffic on it (8000+) concurrent users, so I think the challenge here is in scalability.

Upon the publishing of a new post I want to notify anyone on the site using a modal that a new video or new post is available and allow them to click a link to get to it.

The challenge is in doing that in a realistic time frame (doesn't have to be in in real time), having each connected user hit some script that does some kind of check every INSERT TICK RATE HERE is going to put strain or load on my database. I've looked into the WordPress heartbeat API but I'm curious if anyone has struggled with this before or has any advice in designing such a system.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using memcache or redis for this? when you publish a new post, add an entry to redis with  id, title and permalink, then using a simple php script which directly connects to redis, read the last created post id, title and permalink. when polling, you could send the last post timestamp on the client and return "no-change" from server if the timestamp is not different.